# Override + operator for django field

Tags: django, django-models, operator-overloading

I want to overlay the +- operators for a Django field:

```
x+y --> x | y    (bitwise or)
x-y --> x & (~y) (almost the inverse of above)
```

Where to put the overlay definitions? Below is wrong:

```
class BitCounter(models.BigIntegerField):
    description = "A counter used for statistical calculations"
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase    

    def __radd__(self, other):
       return self | other

   def __sub__(self, other):
      return self & (^other)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create another class which inherits from int:

```
class BitCounter(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self | other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self & (~other)
```

And then return an instance of this class in the to_python method of the field:

```
class BitCounterField(models.BigIntegerField):
    description = "A counter used for statistical calculations"
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase    

    def to_python(self, value):
        val = models.BigIntegerField.to_python(self, value)
        if val is None:
            return val
        return BitCounter(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `myobj.myfield`, you're accessing an object of the type returned by the [field's `to_python` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python), not the field itself. This is due to some of Django's metaclass magic.

---

You probably want to override these methods on the type returned by this method.